# Can't find out why my program won't read analog values

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian, adc, wiringpi

I am using wiringPi and C. I have a flame sensor and a MCP3004 ADC. Here is the program that I wrote, but I can't figure out why it won't read the analog values from the flame sensor.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <mcp3004.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE 200
#define SPI_CHAN 0

int main(void) {

    int channel;
    int x;

    if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
        exit(1);

    mcp3004Setup(BASE, SPI_CHAN);
    for (channel = 0; channel<8; ++channel) {
        x=analogRead(BASE+channel);
        printf("%d\n",x);
        delay(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My program runs but it just outputs 0s. The wiring is correct and the sensors and MCP3004 work fine, I tested it with a python program and it gets the job done.

So the only problem is in my C code.

Comment: Be a LOT more specific - what does "won't read" mean? What values do you get? Any errors? Have you confirmed that the mcp3004 is connected correctly, that it will read an analog voltage at all (use a variable resistor to try it),...

Comment: Sorry. No errors it will just print out eight zero's even with a flame near my fire sensor. I don't have a potentiometer but still the flame sensor has VCC (power up), ground, analog output (which is what i want) and digital output which only outputs 0 or 1.  The mcp3004 is connected correctly i have checked one hundred times. I just don't get why my code won't work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the SPI is actually enabled in raspi-config? Have you tried applying a non-zero voltage to one of the ADC input pins? Could be any sort of problem: wiring, the ADC chip being broken, configuration/code, ... Are you sure your flame detector is outputting a non-zero voltage?

Comment: sorry for late reply i just had to check everything. Everything works i did it with a python program and it works fine. So the problem is my C code one hundred percent. Any ideas? My program still outputs 0s.